# Create group and allow to write, Delete, and read content on a directory

Tags: ubuntu

I own the /var/www directory on my server, and I would like to create a group called webdev, with my admin user in it (tommyadmin).

This group must have permission to create, delete and modify content within /var/www.

This directory belongs to root, but I want to keep him still as the owner of it.

How do I do this procedure?
This group cannot have root permissions.

```
sudo groupadd webdev
sudo adduser tommyadmin webdev
chmod -rwx webdev /var/www
```

Would these be the correct commands?

Comment: No. What's the owner and group of `/var/www`? Read `man chgrp`.

Answer (score 1):

Part of what you have written is right, but you're mixing up `chmod` and `chown`, and you should use `usermod` to add your user to the new group.

```
sudo groupadd webdev
sudo usermod -a -G webdev tommyadmin  # Add tommyadmin to the new webdev group
sudo chgrp -R webdev /var/www         # Recursively change the group owner
sudo chmod 0775 /var/www              # make this directory writable by group
```

However, it could be a bad idea to change the ownership of this directory; if it's served by Apache for instance, that service could require specific ownership depending on what exactly you're doing.  It would perhaps be better to add your account to the existing group ownership to prevent causing problems with the service that is using that directory.

Comment: I would like to keep root as the owner. Is it possible to have root as the owner, but the webdev group can write to the directory?
As I use SFTP, I would need to execute sudo the removal and creation of files in this directory.

Comment: `root` can be the user owner, and `webdev` can be the group owner.  If the directory has `rwxrwxr-x` or `0775` permissions, then `root` or any member of `webdev` can create, modify, or delete files/directories in that directory.  I'm not aware of how you can run `sudo` via `sftp`.